# Forward non-hosted .de email addresses to hosted .com

Tags: email, mx-record

I have a domain with associated web and email hosting package ( let me call it mydomain.com ). I also have a second domain ( mydomain.de ), this one doesn't have email hosting. I would like to make sure that if anybody mistakenly sends an email to niceguy@mydomain.de it shall not get lost and preferably go to niceguy@mydomain.com.

I could have forwarded the niceguy@mydomain.de to niceguy@mydomain.com if I had email hosting for mydomain.de which I don't have and also prefer not to have for simplicity.

How can I setup this kind of forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the DNS records for this domain?
If so, you need to set up some MX records for domain.de that will point to a mail server capable of handling email for that domain.
That mail server could then be configured to forward email to your domain.com address.
If there are no MX records for the domain then email won't go anywhere.
You can use nslookup to check the existing MX records:

- From a command prompt, type nslookup and press enter
- Type 'set type=mx' and press enter
- Type in your domain name and press enter.

The servers returned here will handle the email for that domain.
If there are no servers returned, email will bounce back as undeliverable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set domain.de as alias domain.com if possible on your hosting provider.
2. Set mail-forwarding for domain.de on your Registrar (domain.de) if possible.
3. Use free mail service for domain.de (example pdd.yandex.ru) and forward all messages to domain.com.
4. Use cheap VDS for forward domain.de to domain.com (you need have minimal sysadmin skills).

Comment: We have a web hosting for mydomain.de, but no email hosting. Do I understand correctly that #1 (domain aliasing) would forward both web and email to mydomain.com and our web hosting for mydomain.de would not work anymore (will forward to mydomain.com)?

Comment: No. You need use alias for mail (not for web). Example: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182079